# show detail information when click an image with php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing a website where I want to show products from a database, and when clicking a product it opens a div with more detail info (without refreshing page or going to another).

The product gallery looks like this:

```
<div class="item_galery">
<?php

    $i=0;
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){
        $titulo = $info['titulo'];
        $descr_corta = $info['descr_corta'];
        $img_galeria = $info['img_galeria'];
        $img_detalle = $info['img_detalle'];
        $sub_img1 = $info['sub_img1'];
        $sub_img2 = $info['sub_img2'];
        $sub_img3 = $info['sub_img3'];
        $acabado = $info['acabado'];
        $aux_tamaños = $info['medidas'];
        $tamaños = explode(" ", $aux_tamaños);
        //echo $aux_tamaños.' '.sizeof($tamaños);
        $patron_tornillos = $info['patron_tornillos'];
        $coleccion = $info['coleccion'];

?>          
        <div class="item">      
            <ul><li onclick="mostra_detall(<?php echo $i;?>);"><img alt="" src="<?php echo 'images/llantas/'.$img_galeria; ?>"/></li></ul>
            <ul><li class="descr"><span><?php echo $titulo; ?></span></br><?php echo $acabado; ?></li></ul>
        </div>          

<?php   
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

in the class item, the first li has a js call function wihic shoud open the detail info. This info looks like:

```
<div id="detalle" class="llanta_detalle">
            <img class="foto_gran" src="<?php echo 'images/llantas/'.$img_detalle; ?>">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="cerrar"><ul onclick="tanca_detall(<?php echo $i;?>);"><li><img src="images/llantas/icono_cerrar.jpg"></li><li>CERRAR</li></ul><div class="clear"></div></div>
                <div class="detalle_titol">
                    <ul><li id="titol_llanta" class="titol"><?php echo $titulo; ?></li></ul>
                    <ul><li id="coleccion_llanta" class="coleccion"><?php echo $coleccion; ?></li></ul>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="detalle">       
                    <ul><li class="requadre">ACABADO</li></ul>
                    <ul><li id="acabado_llanta" class="acabado"><?php echo $acabado; ?></li></ul>

                    <ul><li class="requadre">PATRON DE TORNILLOS</li></ul>
                    <ul><li id="tornillos_llanta" class="tornillos"><?php echo $patron_tornillos; ?></li></ul>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="subimagenes"><ul>
                    <li><a id="fancyBox" href="<?php echo 'images/llantas/'.$sub_img1; ?>"><img src="<?php echo 'images/llantas/'.$sub_img1; ?>"></a></li>
                    <li><a id="fancyBox" href="<?php echo 'images/llantas/'.$sub_img2; ?>"><img src="<?php echo 'images/llantas/'.$sub_img2; ?>"></a></li>
                    <li><a id="fancyBox" href="<?php echo 'images/llantas/'.$sub_img3; ?>"><img src="<?php echo 'images/llantas/'.$sub_img3; ?>"></a></li>
                </ul></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
```

my problem is that when the div with detail info is open, I need the specific info from the query of that info, so I would need to do a query or somthing again and do it without refreshing the page. How could I do this?

Thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: Is there a primary key in your table? Use that as arg for `mostra_detall()` instead of `$i`

Comment: Tip: Is not a good practice to declare variable names with special characters such as `ñ`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use Jquery for this. Here is a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_toggle). I gotta go to sleep now, but if you don`t have it done by tomorrow, I will help you! Hope the jquery link helps you though!